# Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy , but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms

Tags: cleos, eosjs, node

my Code

```
    var EosApi = require('eosjs-api');
const Eos = require("eosjs");
// ./cleos create key #OwnerKey
// Private key: 5KVihg2u3yZpBtoLhRGvqf6vBsq9swjyvUkvbpMVMQWz11NbMa2
// Public key: EOS6XViVfWJjLNBkpyPKguP5N3X9Q48mcBezVCPFdkWetFDikNvfR

//  ./cleos create key #ActiveKey
// Private key: 5KKdeNLjW8D9jAAAQFaioshPDci61LKda3DoY3Btzm4evkVooNV
// Public key: EOS6jB1PPcit1t3b9jxMWtzRQ5fTRr1UBHEN67u8yWzPJTQJDUktE

var PrivateOwnerWif = "5KVihg2u3yZpBtoLhRGvqf6vBsq9swjyvUkvbpMVMQWz11NbMa2";
var PublicOwnerWif = "EOS6XViVfWJjLNBkpyPKguP5N3X9Q48mcBezVCPFdkWetFDikNvfR";
var PrivateActiveWif = "5KKdeNLjW8D9jAAAQFaioshPDci61LKda3DoY3Btzm4evkVooNV";
var PublicActiveWif = "EOS6jB1PPcit1t3b9jxMWtzRQ5fTRr1UBHEN67u8yWzPJTQJDUktE";


currencyPrivate = '5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3'
davidPrivate = '5K8jzjyYymX6y3Ltj5r5MzzM3zq6eqeAiiZ3NBexCaAu5Vst43N'
davidPublic = 'EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV'

keyProvider = davidPrivate
chainId = 'cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f'
const Config = {
    httpEndpoint: 'http://192.168.1.10:8888',
    keyProvider: keyProvider,
    chainId: 'cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f',
    expireInSeconds: 60,
    broadcast: true,
    verbose: true,
    sign: true,
    logger: { // Default logging functions
        log: console.log,
        error: console.error
    },
    fetchConfiguration: {}
}
var eos = Eos(Config);
let { ecc } = Eos.modules
// Prepare headers
expireInSeconds = 60 * 60 // 1 hour

transferINVO = async () => {
    info = await eos.getInfo({})
    chainDate = new Date(info.head_block_time + 'Z')
    expiration = new Date(chainDate.getTime() + expireInSeconds * 1000)
    expiration = expiration.toISOString().split('.')[0]

    block = await eos.getBlock(info.last_irreversible_block_num)

    transactionHeaders = {
        expiration,
        ref_block_num: info.last_irreversible_block_num & 0xFFFF,
        ref_block_prefix: block.ref_block_prefix
    }

    keyProvider = davidPrivate
    // keyProvider=currencyPrivate

    // OFFLINE (bring `transactionHeaders`)

    // All keys in keyProvider will sign.
    eos = Eos({ httpEndpoint: null, chainId, keyProvider, transactionHeaders })

    transfer = await eos.transfer('david', 'reza', '0.0001 INV', '')
    transferTransaction = transfer.transaction


    //Online
    eos = Eos({ httpEndpoint: 'http://192.168.1.10:8888', chainId, keyProvider, transactionHeaders })

    processedTransaction = await eos.pushTransaction(transferTransaction)


    // cleos version:
    const cleosTransaction = transferTransaction.transaction
    cleosTransaction.signatures = transferTransaction.signatures
    // `cloes push transaction ${JSON.stringify(cleosTransaction)}`
}

transferINVO()
```

have  error

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Service Error",
    "error": {
        "code": 3090003,
        "name": "unsatisfied_authorization",
        "what": "Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "transaction declares authority '{\"actor\":\"david\",\"permission\":\"active\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], and provided keys [\"EOS53xNMpBLvJmXgUsgSAamFkhKMKdJun8nbktXMmg6zfeHSTzHye\"]",
                "file": "authorization_manager.cpp",
                "line_number": 411,
                "method": "check_authorization"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the keys in your wallet and keep it unlocked?

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing signature signing your transaction. It says you are trying to push it as `david@active`, but to not have authorization attached. Try adding the following options to your transaction construction.

```
const options = {
    authorization: 'david@active',
    broadcast: false,
    sign: false,
  };
```

Comment: was it helpful? can you please mark as correct answer or provide a feedback?

Comment: when transferring the symbol, private_key for sign transaction must belong to from_account(david) and contract_account(eosio.token) must belong to the symbol(INV). This solved my problem