# use inline action with eosio.token

Tags: eosio.token, inline-action

Hello guys i am trying to build a contract that act with eosio.token to make a transfer from my contract using inline action with the eosio.token contract 
here my code

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract("test")]] test:public eosio::contract{
    private:
        void make_transfer(name& from,name& to,asset& quantity,string& memo)
        {
            token::transfer_action transfer{"eosio.token"_n, {from, "active"_n}};
            transfer.send(from,to,quantity, memo);
        }

    public:
        test(name receiver,name code,datastream <const char*> ds):contract(receiver,code,ds){}
        [[eosio::action]]
        void trade(name from,name to ,asset fromcoin,asset tocoin,string memo)
        {
            make_transfer(from,to,fromcoin,memo);
        }

};
```

i got these error

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.

    Error Details:
    transaction declares authority '{"actor":"alice","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"test","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
    pending console output:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy , but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/provided-keys-permissions-and-delays-do-not-satisfy-but-does-not-have-signat)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this like what eosio.system does. eosio.system is usually deployed on `eosio`, privileged account, that can send any action with any permission.

Any inline actions your contract send is executed with permission `YOUR_CONTRACT@eosio.code`. If you want to make USER's token to be transferred by your contract, USER need to add `YOUR_CONTRACT@eosio.code` to `USER@active`. (but it means your contract can send any action with user's active permission)

In this case, it is better to make a notification handler than make your action transfer user's token.

```
[[eosio::on_notify(eosio.token::transfer)]]
void on_token_transfer(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo) {
  do_something_what_you_want_to_do_when_receiving_token();
}
```

Comment: it worked when i added the permission to user but in your code the transfer go  first and it will  run the action after it but if i want to add  some code to my transfer action should i  make the changes to  the eosio.token code?

Comment: No, I might confuse you with my answer. I showed you two ways. [1] Change permission (add eosio.code to user's active permission) [2] Use notification handler (this will make user send transfer to eosio.token, and your contract will handle by being notified from eosio.token). `eosio.token` already has notification logic.

Comment: oh thanks,now it's clear thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue. You have to add your smart contract to the active permission. Check out this answer, it will solve your problem:

https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1718/1010